# How to make a form in django like google form? where user can add or delete field according to their need?User can add up to 10-20 field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Need to create form where users can add or delete fields acc to their need like user can add email, phone no field in the form or like family info, etc or if the user doesn't want that field he can delete the field. Which Django property I can you to create this form or field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not hard to dynamically create a form, although you need something to determine what it should contain for each request. The three-argument form of (Python) `type` can be used. For example,

```
fields = {
  'foo': forms.CharField( max_len=80 )
  'bar': forms.IntegerField() 
}
MyForm = type( 'MyForm', (forms.Form, ), fields)

...
form = MyForm()
```

which is the same as

```
class MyForm( forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField( max_len=80 )
    bar = forms.IntegerField() 

...
form = MyForm()
```

except that you can construct the contents of `fields` dynamically, using some runtime entity to decide what fields with what names and of what type should be in the form.